# Is the Infimum plus $\epsilon$ in the set?

Tags: real-analysis

Let's say I have a set $M = \{ \frac{n+1}{m} \mid n,m \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

The Infimum here is obviously $s = 0$ since $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{m} = 0$. Zero, however is not in the subset.

My question: Is $0+\epsilon$ in the set $\forall \epsilon > 0$? Or generally speaking: Is the $\text{Infimum} + \epsilon$ in the set (providing it doesn't exceed the Supremum)

My initial thought are that $0+\epsilon$ is in the set. But if I choose Epsilon as $\epsilon := \frac{1}{m+1}$ it isn't. But then I could find a m' with $m' = m^2$ that satisfy the fact that Epsilon is in the set.

Can someone show me a valid proof?

Comment: $M$ consists of rational numbers only. Take $\epsilon$ to be any positive irrational.

Comment: Given a set $S$ with infimum $z$, what you can say about $z+\epsilon$ for *all* $\epsilon>0$ is that $S$ has at least one element that is $\leq z+\epsilon$.In other words, $S$ intersects the interval $[z,z+\epsilon]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M$ is a (countable) set of rational numbers, so any irrational $\epsilon$ cannot be in $M$. In fact $M = \mathbb{Q}^+$, the set of positive rationals. Clearly $M \subset \mathbb{Q}^+$, and for any $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ we can assume $a, b > 0$. Then $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{(2a-1)+1}{2b} \in M$$ by definition, since $2a-1 \geq 1$. Hence $\mathbb{Q}^+ \subset M$, so any positive rational $\epsilon$ is in $M$.

[Edit: EuxhenH pointed this out in the comments as I was replying, apologies.]

Comment: Ah, yeah true. Thanks!

Comment: But if epsilon can only be rational, it's in the set right?

Comment: Yes! Your set is actually the set of positive rational numbers, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not know that $\epsilon$ is in the set.  What you know is:
For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $c$ in the set with $0 < c < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!